# How can I get a selector from jQuery based on attribute

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

If I have this HTML:

```
<a id="test" referenceId="test23" href=''>Test</a>
```

and I want to get the selector based on the `referenceId` attribute (not the `id`)

I know I can do this

```
$('#test'). . ..
```

but I want to understand if I can do a similar thing but using the `referenceId` attribute to get the selector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching from attribute values should not be done directly on the root document, and especially not using a very generic selector as it is quite slow, and should be limited to a specific parent, a specific tag name, or on elements with a shared CSS class. For example, in your case, if `referenceId` is an attribute only specified to anchor elements, you query :

```
$("a[referenceId='someValue']")...
```

If you have this attribute on different tag names, you can narrow the search specifying a common parent, or using multiple selectors, etc. in the same query. For example :

```
$("div#parent [referenceId='someValue']")... // use div#parent as base element
$("a[referenceId='someValue'], span[referenceId='someValue']")... // search A and SPAN tags only
$(".ref[referenceId='someValue']")... // search any element with "ref" CSS class
// etc.
```

Note that it is recommended to enclose the attribute value in quotes. You can read more about selectors from the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 4):

`$('[referenceId="test23"]')`

Answer (score 3):

`$('[attribute=someValue]'). . . .`